# Switching editors in Eclipse with keyboard, rather than switching Design/Source

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, I can switch through open editors using control-page up/down. This works great, except for editors like XML or JavaScript, where there are Design and Source tabs. For those editors, it just toggles between the different tabs. Is there any way to get Eclipse to ignore them? I know about alt-F6 for "Next Editor", but that doesn't use the same order that the editor tabs are displayed in, so it's confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right -- looks like Eclipse has acknowledged it as a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=199499). It's fixed in 3.5.

Answer (score 3):

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> you can jump directly to any editor by typing the beginning of it's name. Quite handy when you've got a lot of editors open.

Answer (score 0):

I was initially thinking <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd> might do what you want, but that's more for going forward and backwards in history of tabs you've viewed. Which might sort of get you what you want, but is probably just as confusing as <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>.

I think it sounds more like a bug in Eclipse, might be worth going over to eclipse.org to see if there's a pre-existing bug for this.